# I use selenium(python) to retrieve some data from WOS top papers, but when I use click() to open the sub link, I can only open the first url

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler, spyder

My task is to open each url from the following website and retrieve some evaluation data for each essay. I have located the element successfully, which means I get 10  element. However, when selenium began to imitate human to click the url, it can only open the first link of ten links.
https://esi.clarivate.com/DocumentsAction.action
[image]

HTML:[image]

[image]

The code is as followed.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver


driver=webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://esi.clarivate.com/IndicatorsAction.action?Init=Yes&SrcApp=IC2LS&SID=H3-M1jrs4mSS2O3WTFbtdrUJugtDvogGRIM-18x2dx2B1ubex2Bo9Y5F6ZPQtUZbfUAx3Dx3Dp1StTsneXx2B7vu85UqXoaoQx3Dx3D-03Ff2gF3hTJGBPDScD1wSwx3Dx3D-cLUx2FoETAVeN3rTSMreq46gx3Dx3D')

#add filter-> research fields-> "clinical medicine"
target = driver.find_element_by_id("ext-gen1065")
time.sleep(1)
target.click()
time.sleep(1)

n = driver.window_handles
driver.switch_to.window(n[-1])

links=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("docTitle")
length=len(links)
for i in range(0,length):
    item=links[i]
    item.click()
    time.sleep(1)


    handles=driver.window_handles  
    index_handle=driver.current_window_handle  
    for handle in handles: 
        if handle != index_handle:  
            driver.switch_to.window(handle)  
        else:
            continue            
    time.sleep(1)
    u1=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("large-number")[2].text
    u2=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("large-number")[3].text
    print(u1,u2)
    print("\n")
    driver.close()
    time.sleep(1)

    driver.switch_to_window(index_handle)
driver.quit()
print("————finished————")
```

The error page:
[image]

And I try to find out the problem by testing these code:

```
links=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("docTitle")
length=len(links)
print(length)
print(links[1].text)
#links[0].click()
links[1].click()
```

The result is:
[image]
which means it had already find the element, but failed to open it.(when using links[0].text, it works fine.)
Any idea about this?

Comment: post the html of the page in question. Also please post the error message you get when the click fails.

Comment: To access the page it requires login credentials. You need to post the Relevant HTML?

Comment: Thanks. I've post the relevant HTML and error message.